# how can I count my command history to a shell variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I am using the script below to count my command history, but always get 0, how can I count my history to a shell variable?

```sh
#! /bin/bash
count=$(history | wc -l)
echo $count
```

Comment: If you want history line count for your interactive shell, try running `. name-of-script` or `source name-of-script`.  Also try `echo $HISTCMD`

Comment: As @Milag has outlined history pertains to the current shell and so running the script without source will run the history command in another bash shell with no history

Comment: how can I run source name-of-script in the same script file? seems impossible

Answer (score 0):

First you have to activate the shell builtin `history` in your script:

```
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
```

After that you can use your source code.

Comment: but seems the count result from the script and run the command directly are not equal, why this happen? any method to make them be the same?

Comment: Seems the .bash_history file differs from the history command, but if i logout/login they are nearly the same. Seems history cache the lines before delete it in .bash_history.